# Squared euclidean calculation with cell arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, functional-programming, vectorization

I start a university project in a few months and initially planned to write it in Java but my tutor recommended me to pick up Matlab as it will be a lot easier and efficient, so I'm writing a few proof of concept prototypes to 'test the waters'.

Right now I have a cell array and I want to find the total **Sum of Squares** for the elements in the (cell) array. In other words, I need to go through each element, find its mean, then calculate the distance each point in the element is from this mean, then total this up for each element and return a single figure for the entire array.

This is how I approached it:

```
function squared_sum = sumsquares(c_array)
squared_sum = 0
for i = 1:size(c_array,2)
    c_element = cell2mat(c_array(1,i));
    for j = 1:size(c_element,1)
        square_distance = pdist2(c_element(j,:), mean(c_array{1,i})).^2; % sum of squares = euclidean distance squared
        squared_sum = squared_sum + square_distance;
    end
end
end
```

The issue is that this is exactly how I would write it in Java. I'm aware that the functional paradigm is supposed to be more elegant and less reliant on loops so I'm curious about if there is a nicer way to write this?

edit: cell structure (1x4) is something like [28x3] [42x3] [8x3] [91x3]

Comment: What does `c_array` look like? Add a sample case?

Comment: Make sure you double-check your source code to ensure it runs before posting.  There's already an error on the fourth line of your code (i.e. missing parenthesis).

Comment: If the cell structure is `(1x4)` and the cells are `[28x3]` `[42x3]` `[8x3]` `[91x3]`, won't it throw error at `cell2mat(c_array{1,i})`?

Comment: You're right. It should be cell2mat(c_array(1,i)), apologies (I had copy & paste issues surprisingly).

Comment: Avoid using `i`, `j`, and `sum` while coding in MATLAB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For regular shaped cell arrays ( cells of the same size), you could use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) like so -

```
c_array3D = cat(3,c_array{:});
sqdiffs = bsxfun(@minus,c_array3D,mean(c_array3D,1)).^2;
squared_sum = sum(sqdiffs(:));
```

For irregular shaped cell arrays, you could reduce the loop complexity by using `pdist2` to work on 2D arrays instead of 1D arrays, like so -

```
squared_sum = 0;
for i = 1:size(c_array,2)
    squared_sum = squared_sum + sum(pdist2(c_array{1,i}, mean(c_array{1,i})).^2);
end
```

Comment: Wow it's amazing how much faster the program runs when using 1 loop instead of 2. This is cool, thanks!

Comment: @JHick Try to switch the ordering of the loops in your original script and see what happens.

Comment: @JHick You have just been Divakar'ed, which is our way of saying that you got served a plate of vectorization and fast code.  I hope you enjoyed the experience! BTW, nice job again Divakar. +1.

Comment: @rayryeng I just got verb-ed eh! :)